# Open picklist over scrollbar

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, developer, scrolling

I'm trying to show a picklist over the scrollbar of my lwc.

I tried with z-index and overflow in some places but I don't find how to do that (maybe it's impossible?).

Here an example code that I wrote to demonstrate.

In the native code (lightning-combobox), the picklist is under the scrollbar of the component and in the code HTML basic, it's over.

JS

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class TestDropdownOverComponent extends LightningElement {
    seasonList = [
        {
           "label":"qqqqqqq",
           "value":"qqqqqq"
        },
        {
           "label":"qqqqqqq",
           "value":"qqqqqq"
        },
        {
           "label":"qqqqqqq",
           "value":"qqqqqq"
        },
        {
           "label":"qqqqqqq",
           "value":"qqqqqq"
        },
        {
           "label":"qqqqqqq",
           "value":"qqqqqq"
        },
    ];
}
```

HTML

```
<template>
    <div class="slds-scrollable_x lwc-component">
      <div class="slds-grid">
        <div class="slds-form-element slds-col slds-size_2-of-3">
            <lightning-combobox
                class="slds-combobox_container slds-p-vertical_medium combobox"
                name="myCombobox"
                label="Select an option"
                placeholder="Select an option"
                options={seasonList}
                ref="combobox"
            ></lightning-combobox>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-form-element slds-col slds-size_2-of-3">
          <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="select-01">Select a Value</label>
          <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-select_container">
              <select class="slds-select" id="select-05">
                <option>Option One</option>
                <option>Option Two</option>
                <option>Option Three</option>
                <option>Option Four</option>
                <option>Option Five</option>
                <option>Option Six</option>
                <option>Option Seven</option>
                <option>Option Eight</option>
                <option>Option Nine</option>
                <option>Option Ten</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-form-element slds-col slds-size_2-of-3">
          <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="select-01">Select a Value</label>
          <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-select_container">
              <select class="slds-select" id="select-02">
                <option>Option One</option>
                <option>Option Two</option>
                <option>Option Three</option>
                <option>Option Four</option>
                <option>Option Five</option>
                <option>Option Six</option>
                <option>Option Seven</option>
                <option>Option Eight</option>
                <option>Option Nine</option>
                <option>Option Ten</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-form-element slds-col slds-size_2-of-3">
          <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="select-01">Select a Value</label>
          <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <div class="slds-select_container">
              <select class="slds-select" id="select-03">
                <option>Option One</option>
                <option>Option Two</option>
                <option>Option Three</option>
                <option>Option Four</option>
                <option>Option Five</option>
                <option>Option Six</option>
                <option>Option Seven</option>
                <option>Option Eight</option>
                <option>Option Nine</option>
                <option>Option Ten</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

CSS

```
.lwc-component {
    height: 190px;
    overflow-x: overlay;
}

.combobox {
    z-index: 1;
}
```